# XCode 4 says, "Argument Invalid" on attempt to run project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I had a project initially created in XCode 3 and used it successfully in XCode 4 Developer Preview version.

After upgrading to XCode 4 release, any time I try to run the project on the device, I get a "Argument Invalid" dialog. Except it doesn't tell me what argument.

How does one figure out what is wrong and why I can't run the app on my device any more?

Base SDK is set to 4.3
Deployment target set to: iOS 4.2

Comment: I uninstalled XCode completely and reinstalled it - that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 17):

Ok, I have just managed to sort this out as I was having the same issue.  This may not help you, but for me it was because I had a symlink inside a folder included in the project.  I've removed this, and now it all works fine.  Interestingly it works fine on the simulator in this case.

I've filed a bug with Apple on the issue (#9168893).

Comment: I worked around this by using an alias created using Finder -> right click source folder -> Make alias.

It turns out that the alias caused the problem on my machine was created using "ln -s <source> <target>"

Comment: @user547539 Ah interesting! Yes, my alias was created via ln -s.

Comment: That strange that they have this issue since 2011, thanks I would have never though of the sym link was creating the problem

Comment: For viewing all symlinks in project dir do this `find ./ -type l -exec ls -l {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

Just clean your producto

**Menu>Product>Clean (Shift+Cmd+K)**

Answer (score 0):

I got the following message **argument is invalid** in response to some kind of **USB weirdness**.  Sometimes it goes away if I unplug and replug the device, but what turns out to fix it more reliably is to start up **iTunes**.  Usually, when I do this, the problematic device doesn't appear in the **DEVICES list at first**, but does after a few seconds, and once it does, the **device and Xcode** get along fine.