# iphone deploy to device

Tags: ios, xcode4, cordova

I hope someone can help, I am pulling my hair out for a little bit. I am trying to test an application on 3GS iphone with XCODE 4. The application will deploy to the simulator but deploying to the device I get "The argument is invalid". I am using phonegap.0.9.6.js and I optional linked UIKit, CoreMedia, and AVFoundation. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253869/xcode-4-says-argument-invalid-on-attempt-to-run-project

Can't use symlinks in a project. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else.