# Xcode - "The Argument Is Invalid"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, symlink, beta-testing

I am trying to create an Ad-hoc version for beta testing(.ipa extension) of an ios app I made. The problem is that whenever you try to install the app via Xcode>Organizer>DEVICE>Applications>Add I get a message saying "The argument is invalid". The app installs just fine on the simulator and all of my devices with no warning or errors if you installing it via the "Build and Run" button. I just get this message when trying to install the .ipa. I have double checked the Provisioning Profile and the device(s) are correctly added. I am code signing the project to the "iPhone Distribution" Profile with all of the correct devices. Also, from reading similar questions on here ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253869/xcode-4-says-argument-invalid-on-attempt-to-run-project),[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576127/argument-invalid-with-every-build-in-xcode)) I though it might be a symlink problem. I removed all of the symlinks and still get this error. I ran

```
find ./ -type l -exec ls -l {} \;
```

to find all the symlinks and after fixing all of them when I run that command it doesn't return anything.

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using a distribution profile?

Comment: I wasn't but now I just signed it with a distribution profile and the exact same error is still happening :(

Comment: I so want to post a link to Nicholas Cage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After nearly 8 hours of messing with Xcode I figured it out. It turns out that the Appirater library, which I had included via Cocoapods, had 1 symbolic link that was messing everything up. I just installed Appirater myself(and removed it from Cocoapods) and now everything works fine. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem in the future. :)